# Xcode ui test: staticTexts start with

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I want to check if an element on my ui which start with a prefix is present. How is it possible to implement it in Xcode 7 UI Tests?

```
app.tables["AAA"].staticTexts["Fax: 0049XXXXXXXX"].exists
```

I have three element into a tableview cell and only one (the third or last one) starts with the prefix Fax: 0049. How can i check the present of this element?

I tried with

```
app.tables["AAA"].cells.staticTexts.elementBoundByIndex(2).exists
```

But nothing, some ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a `BEGINSWITH` predicate to check if an element starts with a prefix.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let faxPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'Fax: '")
let faxLabel = app.staticTexts.element(matching: faxPredicate)
XCTAssert(faxLabel.exists)
```

Here's a working example for selecting elements with a different `BEGINSWITH` predicate, [a picker with multiple wheels](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#picker-with-multiple-wheels).

Comment: I was confused by the difference between staticTexts.matching(predicate) and staticTexts.element(matching: predicate). Quite subtle!

Comment: Whoever stumbles on this like I did, you can also use `ENDSWITH` to check the end of labels.