# How to wait for a label to appear with character count greater than zero UI Test

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

Actually before api call only Label is visible with empty text. After getting response label character count is greater than zero. But here how can wait for label appear with character count greater than zero and perform some action.

This is the code I used but I am getting predicate error

caught “NSUnknownKeyException” , “[<_NSCFString 0xjel990> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this is not key value coding-complaint for the key characters

```
func testForWishListCountIsReflecting() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.decide()
    cellTap()
    app.navigationBars["MMRecoPageView"].buttons["MenuButton"].tap()

    let wishListLable =  app.staticTexts["WishListLabel"]
    wishListLable.label.characters

    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "label.characters.count > 0")

    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject:wishListLable, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: nil)


    let expectedValue:String = app.staticTexts["WishListLabel"].value as! String
    app.buttons["Wishlist"].tap()

   XCTAssertTrue(app.tables.cells.count == UInt(expectedValue))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the error message.  The `characters()` selector cannot be used in an `NSPredicate` because it does not work with KVO.

> this is not key value coding-compliant for the key `characters`

I suggest a slightly different approach. Do you know what the actual text *should* be? If so, you can change your predicate to match exactly for that. You can remove manually set the "WishListLabel" accessibility and let the content set it automatically.

```
func testForWishListCountIsReflecting() {
    // ...setup...         
    let wishListLabel = app.staticTexts["contents of label"]
    waitForElementToAppear(wishListLabel)
}

private func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement, file: String = __FILE__, line: UInt = __LINE__) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 5 seconds."
            self.recordFailureWithDescription(message, inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: text will be like 1 or 2.. some unique string formatted number. In your code you told let the content automatically ,but here label is empty initially before getting response . should i write some think like app.staticTexts[""]. if i write this after 5 seconds same empty text is coming even actual value came in response

Comment: The query is re-evaluated every so often until the label is found or it times out. So you shouldn't use an empty query as you asked.I've set a five-second timeout in the example above. If you don't know the *exact* label contents, the test becomes harder to write. You could use a [`BEGINSWITH` predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510779/384110) if you know what the content starts with.